# Jest Coverage fails when using jest.config resetMocks: 'true'

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage

I am using jest config in my package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 80,
        "functions": 80,
        "lines": 80,
        "statements": 80
      },
      "resetMocks": true,
      "restoreMocks": true
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/index.js",
      "!src/setupTests.js",
      "!src/serviceWorker.js",
      "!src/setupApollo.js",
      "!src/test/**/*",
      "!src/mockData/**/*",
      "!src"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "cobertura",
      "json",
      "json-summary",
      "lcov"
    ]
  },
```

All of my coverage parameters pass except I get the following messages at the end:

Jest: Coverage data for resetMocks was not found.
Jest: Coverage data for restoreMocks was not found.

How can exclude those two jest methods from coverage?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your issue - your reset/restore are within the coverageThreshold object, move them outside.

```
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 80,
        "functions": 80,
        "lines": 80,
        "statements": 80
      },
    },
    "resetMocks": true,
    "restoreMocks": true
```

What you are resetting is apparently flaky, try below [GH](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7136) thread if you are interested.

```
resetMocks: true,
resetModules: true
```